# Ребят, подскажите пожалуйста как сделать заполнение формы при нажатии на первый инпут? то есть нажали на первый инпут - все поля формы заполнились

Tags: javascript, form, input

Пробовал сделать, что то не получается(

```js
function fillText() {
  document.getElementById('1').value = 'Vasya Pupkin';
  document.getElementById('2').value = '20.07.1994';
  document.getElementById('3').value = '89774851454';
  document.getElementById('4').value = 'elananet@yandex.ru';
  document.getElementById('5').value = 'MSU programer';
  document.getElementById('6').value = 'Three years of carwashing';
}
```

```css
.bottom .fill_form-content form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.bottom .fill_form-content form .personal_data {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.bottom .fill_form-content form .personal_data input {
  width: 20vw;
  height: 74px;
  opacity: 0.3;
  background: #D8D8D8;
  border: 3px solid #979797;
  border-radius: 13px;
  font-family: Avenir-Light;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #000000;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  line-height: 55px;
  margin: 25px 25px;
}

.bottom .fill_form-content form .education_data {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.bottom .fill_form-content form .education_data textarea {
  width: 29vw;
  height: 198px;
  opacity: 0.3;
  background: #D8D8D8;
  border: 3px solid #979797;
  border-radius: 13px;
  font-family: Avenir-Light;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #000000;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  line-height: 55px;
  margin: 25px 25px;
}

.bottom .fill_form-content form .additional_data {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.bottom .fill_form-content form .additional_data textarea {
  width: 29vw;
  height: 198px;
  opacity: 0.3;
  background: #D8D8D8;
  border: 3px solid #979797;
  border-radius: 13px;
  font-family: Avenir-Light;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #000000;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  line-height: 55px;
  margin: 25px 25px;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <div class="personal_data">
    <input id="1" onclick="fillText()" type="text" placeholder=" Name*">
    <input id="2" type="text" placeholder=" Date of birth*">
    <input id="3" type="tel" placeholder=" Mobile*">
    <input id="4" type="email" placeholder=" E-mail*">
  </div>
  <div class="education_data">
    <textarea id="5" rows="3" placeholder=" Your education*"></textarea>
    <textarea id="6" rows="3" placeholder=" Your work experience*"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="additional_data">
    <textarea id="7" rows="3" placeholder=" Your main skills*"></textarea>
    <textarea id="8" rows="3" placeholder=" Additional information"></textarea>
    <div class="additional_data-buttons">
      <button>Upload file…</button>
      <button id="apply">Apply</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: У меня иногда бывает так в google chrome, я использую cntrl + f5.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю как у тебя, скопировал - заробатало, как вариант использовать on click По второму методу, то есть через js, а не html

https://learn.javascript.ru/introduction-browser-events

```
<form action="">
                <div class="personal_data">
                    <input id="1" type="text" placeholder=" Name*">
                    <input id="2" type="text" placeholder=" Date of birth*">
                    <input id="3" type="tel" placeholder=" Mobile*">
                    <input id="4" type="email" placeholder=" E-mail*">
                </div>
                <div class="education_data">
                    <textarea id="5" rows="3" placeholder=" Your education*"></textarea>
                    <textarea id="6" rows="3" placeholder=" Your work experience*"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="additional_data">
                    <textarea id="7" rows="3" placeholder=" Your main skills*"></textarea>
                    <textarea id="8" rows="3" placeholder=" Additional information"></textarea>
                    <div class="additional_data-buttons">
                        <button>Upload file…</button>
                        <button id="apply">Apply</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

убираешь в форме on click, а js фкнцкия

```
var dict = {
    1 : "Vasya Pupkin",
    2 : "20.07.1994",
    3 : "89774851454",
    4 : "elananet@yandex.ru",
    5 : "MSU programer",
    6 : "Three years of carwashing"
};

document.getElementById('1').onclick = function() {

  for(var i in dict) {
    document.getElementById(i).value = dict[i]; 
  }

  this.blur();

};
```

Или же если это принципиальо можно также сделать

```
var dict = {
        1 : "Vasya Pupkin",
        2 : "20.07.1994",
        3 : "89774851454",
        4 : "elananet@yandex.ru",
        5 : "MSU programer",
        6 : "Three years of carwashing"
};

function fillText() {
  for(var i in dict) {
    document.getElementById(i).value = dict[i]; 
      this.blur();

  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ) первый предложенный вариант срабатывает, но срабатывает при нажатии двух раз на инпут. Можно ли как то сделать так, чтобы сразу, с первого клика?

Comment: Я думаю, правильнее было бы использовать onfocus

Comment: @Дмытрык не мог бы код набросать?пожалуйста. пробовал с фокусом, не получилось что то

Comment: Там получается он фокусируется и уже отлавливается focus, поэтому click не срабатывает, просто в любом случае если использовать onfocus как предложили, актуальность input теряется, он становится кнопкой

Comment: @DimaKaukin спасибо)